# "Даже если" - расстановка запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с расстановкой запятых. Предложение такого типа: "Этот документ нужно получать(,) даже(,) если товар не подлежит обязательной сертификации". Я расставила так: "Этот документ нужно получить, даже если товар..." Но засомневалась - ведь перед "если" обычно ставится запятая.
Правильно ли у меня расставлены запятые и, если нет, то как нужно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы расставили знаки правильно. ДАЖЕ - усилительная частица, от союза ЕСЛИ её отделять не нужно.

Сложные союзы **тогда как, словно как, в то время как, между тем как, союз следствия так что**, сочетание союза с усилительной частицей **даже если**, **лишь когда** не расчленяются.***  [Розенталь Д.Э.](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm)

Comment: Большое спасибо! А то постоянно путаю.